# Composition Series of the regular A-module

Tags: representation-theory

Assume A is a finite-dimensional algebra over field K. How can we prove that any simple A-module occurs, as a composition factor (up to isomorphism) of an arbitrary composition series of A, as module over itself at least once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a standard result (usually called the Jordan-Hölder theorem) that any two composition series have the same length and the same factors, up to a permutation. More precisely, if
$$
0=I_0<I_1<\dots<I_{n-1}<I_m=A,
\qquad
0=J_0<J_1<\dots<J_{n-1}<J_n=A
$$
are composition series, then $m=n$ and there is a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ such that
$$
I_k/I_{k-1}\cong J_{\sigma(k)}/J_{\sigma(k)-1}
$$
for $k=1,2,\dots,m$.

So you just need to show that any simple module appears in at least *one* composition series. If $S$ is a simple module, then $S\cong A/M$, for a maximal (right) ideal. Extend $A>M$ to a composition series.

Comment: thank you for your reply, to be honest, i completely understand Jordan-Holder here. But i don't understand how do we make the last extension that you mentioned. Always exists?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris Yes: take a maximal submodule of $M$, and go on (Schreier refinement theorem).

Comment: thank you very much for your help!